# How to test for sending emails in python?

Tags: python, testing, smtplib

I'm writing a set of black box tests for my application.
I'm using smtplib for sending the emails, and I want to test whether emails are being sent/received properly.

Any ideas on how to do that in python?

Comment: testing is easy - python will tell you if there was a problem handing off the email. receiving - only way to do that is to actually send an email and see what arrives.

Comment: The issue is I have multiple recipients and I want to make sure that they all received it.

Comment: there's no 100% reliable way to do that. mail servers are known to accept mail and then silently drop it in the trash if they decide it's spam. you can try webbugs, but those rarely if EVER work in modern mail clients, you can try read-receipts, but most people never allow/send those, blah blah blah.

Comment: I had to go with Marc suggestion and make the test very simplistic. If the server doesn't complain, it passes.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following to test that your emails are sent.

- [FakeSMTP](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/)
- [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/)
- [Fake smtp in python](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/fake-smtp-server-with-python/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog),

you can run it locally using the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/)